Reattaching ceiling mounted roller blinds in drywall
Before we moved in, the ceiling in the study had been lowered using drywall to put in built-in lights. This means that the ceiling mounted roller blinds in turn had been mounted to the same drywall. Now, I don't know much about construction, but I just assumed that there would have been a stud along the wall that the roller blinds could be attached to. I found out today that this very much is not the case as a long blind came crashing down and nearly hit my one year old toddler in the head.
I am at a loss as how to fix this. Is there any way to reinforce and then reattach the blinds in the ceiling without ripping up the drywall?
The sun here is punishing during the day so it will basically be impossible to use the study at all until this is fixed. I am hoping for the least intrusive solution (as my skills are extremely low) but any tips on how to proceed would be incredibly appreciated!

Some pics would surely help you out here...

Please modify your question to describe the exact situation of your windows and ceiling, what materials the walls and original ceiling are made of, and include some pictures.  You'll then get good answers about how to fix this properly!   Please don't suggest that neither you nor anyone in your country is capable of doing this right.  That's not how good questions are asked here, and I assure you, YOU can do this if you want, and there ARE good people no matter where you are.  The right details will get you the right answer.
